# 4K@60Hz MacBook Pro Late 2013

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I recently got a 4K 60Hz monitor for my 13" MacBook Pro Late 2013. It supports both HDMI and DisplayPort, but since the included cable is a full-sized DisplayPort cable, I'm currently using HDMI. Back when the rMBP Late 2013 came out, [an article](http://alex4d.com/notes/item/macbook-pros-run-4k-display-at-60hz) wrote about how it could support 4K@60Hz, but only on Windows because of a driver issue. I was wondering if that issue has since been fixed, and if it is possible for me to run my monitor at 60Hz.

I also tried to run it at 1440p@60Hz, using both System Preferences and cscreen, but neither of them worked. If it is impossible for me to use 4K@60Hz but it is with 1440p@60Hz, could you please let me know how? I am willing to purchase a MiniDP to DP cable if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a different experience than the people here.

I have a "MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)".
All signs pointed to the macbook not being able to do 4k @ 60 hz.

I got a display port<-> mini display port cable.
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B013PWQN1Y/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

and a 4k ultra wide monitor
https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/curved/32-ur59c-curved-4k-uhd-monitor-lu32r590cwnxza/


and with this setup my 5-6 year old macbook is pumping out :
U32R59x:
  Resolution: 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz

Answer (score 4):

I recently purchased a 4K monitor and found out that my 13" MacBook Pro Late 2013 does not support 4K@60Hz even with the Mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort adapter. It only supports 4K@30Hz.

According to Apple's support document, 4K@60Hz with a multi-stream transport (MST) display is only supported by 15" model of the same age:

> These Mac computers support MST displays at 60Hz:
>
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, **15-inch, Late 2013**) and later MacBook Pro
> - MacBook Pro (Retina, **13-inch, Early 2015**) and later

Source: [Using 4K displays, 5K displays, and Ultra HD TVs with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587)

Comment: It's useable, but you will notice the low refresh rate easily from mouse cursor movement, for example.

Comment: Well, it works just fine as for me. Also the Displays menu does not have the Frequency selector which makes me think that it's 60Hz despite the specs. Can't see the lags also.

Answer (score 1):

HDMI is limited to a resolution of Full HD (1080p) at 60Hz.  4K is limited to 30Hz.

From the Apple Tech Specs for the [Late 2013 13" MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP691?locale=en_US)

> **HDMI video output**
>
> - Support for 1080p resolution at up to 60Hz
> - Support for 3840-by-2160 resolution at 30Hz
> - Support for 4096-by-2160 resolution at 24Hz

However, (IMO) you shouldn't be using HDMI.   DisplayPort should give you the performance you are looking for.  What you will need is a [mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable](http://radnex.us/mini-display-port-to-display-port) that is capable of supporting 4K bandwidth.

Also, according to Apple's support document [Using 4K displays, 5K displays, and Ultra HD TVs with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587), to get 60Hz refresh on your model, you need to make sure you are using an MST (multi-stream transport) display and that it's capable/enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, even when I set the monitor to 1080p, I can't increase the frame rate to 60Hz. Would the miniDP to DP cable have the same issue?

Comment: As long as you get one that supports the higher refresh.

Comment: thanks again. For the time being, is there any way I could get this to run at 1440p@60Hz over HDMI?

Comment: Over HDMI?  No; not going to happen as it simply isn't supported.  Also, make sure your display *can* support the refresh rate and it is enabled.  See the edit (link) for more info.

Comment: Yeah, I know my display supports 60Hz, and it is enabled. I'll look into getting the cable, thanks.

Comment: The HDMI in the Mac is not new enough to run at the higher speeds required to do what you want.