# How to connect an early 2013 MBP to a 4K LG Television

Tags: macbook-pro, 4k

I've seen some people on YouTube saying they were able to connect an early 2013 MAC Book Pro with some 4K Monitors. I bought an 4K LG TV. It seems that I can't connect using 60Hz. I already tried the Thunderbolt connector and couldn't make it. Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Does that model have a HDMI connector? My mid-2014 does, and it works fine with a 4K screen. Didn't need to use the Thunderbolt connectors.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean "tried the Thunderbolt connector."  You may also want to view this related post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313728/4k60hz-macbook-pro-late-2013/313775#313775

Answer (score 1):

Most Macs with an HDMI port (besides Mac mini late-2012 and older) support 4K, but are capped at 30Hz or 24Hz. [The MacBook Pro Retina 15" mid-2014 model supports 60Hz at 4K, but older models do not.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587)

I personally have a MacBook Pro Retina 15" late-2013 model, and it can only do 4K at 30Hz

(4K is defined in my answer as 3840 x 2160.)